# Is it possible/what happens when you clear the pool table?

Tags: duke-nukem-forever

In Duke Nukem Forever, right near the start of the game before you get in the lift, there is a pool or snooker table.

I have been trying for ages now to clear the table by sinking all the balls, and am getting fed up, but, the closest I can get is one ball away before potting the white and the game restarting.

I am guessing it is possible, but does anyone know what happens?

Comment: Since it doesn't award an achievement, it's likely to be an Ego boost, if anything. Can't say for sure, because I haven't done it yet...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Right, after what must of been around an hour of trying, I finally managed to do it!

Duke says "Too easy"

The twins say "You're the best, Duke"

And, Lunboks was correct, you get +2 ego.

This early on in the game, I am not sure how valuable 2 Ego is, but, I can tell you this was the most boring waste of time! I have heard the "s***" word probably close to 100 times and whilst funny... it gets so boring!

To anyone else trying, a little hint is that if you think the white ball is about to go in, try hitting it again as you do not need to wait for it to finish, and if it goes too fast, instead of going in, it just bounces again.

Comment: [There are spoiler tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1191/163265 "meta.so: Add markdown support for hidden-until-you-click text (aka spoilers)"), but this only answers your question, so they're hardly necessary.

Comment: @lunboks ahh, ok, no problem! Just didn't know the policy here and didn't want to annoy anyone!

Answer (score 0):

All you get is ego boost for completing it but let me answer your question on how to do it.
I've completed this game multiple times every single time I spend at least an hour or two an hour and a half trying to play it by eventually giving up when I get back to it what I do is you first start out hitting the ball in it knocks them all into a line it depends on where you're standing how far away you are from it and where your crosshair is I've had multiple shots where I was able to hit it and knock it in or bounce off by the broken physics it all depends on how or where you're standing I've been down to one ball knocked the one ball in but also Walk to Walk knocked in the white bowl so there is a way to do it you just have to have patience necessarily I don't at the moment but if you need any more help I'm more than happy to help you I might just do a video explaining the physics and how you're supposed to play this it's all based on aiming like where your acrosser is how far away like in real pool

Comment: Hi dumpsterman, can you *please* add punctuation?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).